# php.ini absent from xampp\apache\bin.

Tags: php, apache, configuration, ini

I recently installed XAMPP on Windows 7, and my phpinfo() says it is loading the configuration file from `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

There's no php.ini in my apache\bin directory.

Copying and pasting the file and restarting Apache also didn't work..

Comment: And what about `C:\xampp\php\​`?

Comment: It's ok to be in C:\xampp\php folder.

Comment: @Sheikh: I am trying to get xdebug running, and articles everywhere specify the php.ini in apache\bin..

Comment: @Gumbo C:\xampp\php\​ has a php.ini and it is being loaded by phpinfo()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to say this, but read the man! lol.  http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php  Configure your apache installation to look for the php.ini file in a specified location  http://www.askapache.com/php/custom-phpini-tips-and-tricks.html#path_environment_variable_PHPRC  Hopefully you won't need to recompile your copy to remove a predefined location of the php.ini file.